# map for a single value

Tags: ruby, dictionary

There are a string and a proc object.
The proc object is used to manipulate the string.

s = "10"

p = Proc.new { |i| i.to_i }

[s].map(&p).first #=> 10

This works. But is there a better way to do that when s and p are given?

Thanks.

Sam

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>> p.call(s)
p.call(s)
=> 10
```

If I understand your question correctly, you just want the proc to manipulate the string?

Comment: Instead of call you could also use `p[s]`, which has the same effect.

Comment: Hmmm, why didn't I think of it? Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

in 1.9 you can do `p.(s)`